# C# list in function param

Tags: c#, list

I'm new to C#. I want to take a list as argument and return another from the data I get from the first one.

```
private List<DestinationGenericMapProps> ConstructDestinationMapPropsList(List<BoutiqueInWebService> datas)
{
    var result = new List<DestinationGenericMapProps>(datas);
    return result;
}
```

I get this error:

> Error 241 The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<VDDataUpdaterGeneric.DataObjects.DestinationGenericMapProps>.List(int)` has some invalid arguments

I know this is probably pretty basic but I'm new to C# and struggle with this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are `BoutiqueInWebService` and `DestinationGenericMapProps` related in any way?

Comment: You can use the `Select` LINQ extension method to generate a `List` of another type (`DestinationGenericMapProps` in your case) from a list of a non-related type (`BoutiqueInWebService` in your case). Something like `datas.Select(boutique => DestinationGenericMapProps.FromBoutique(boutique)).ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method return type is a list of `DestinationGenericMapProps`, but you're trying to create list of `BoutiqueInWebService` (which is data).

You can do this to match your return type:

```
private List<DestinationGenericMapProps> 
        ConstructDestinationMapPropsList(List<BoutiqueInWebService> datas)
{
    return (from d in datas
            select new DestinationGenericMapProps()
            {
                // map properties here
                Prop1 = d.SomePropInData
            }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`List<BoutiqueInWebService>` is not a `List<DestinationGenericMapProps>`.

This will not work unless `BoutiqueInWebService` is derived from `DestinationGenericMapProps`.

Basically, there is a `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor, but the T's have to be the same.

Either change your return type to `List<BoutiqueInWebService>` and change your new statement:

```
private List<BoutiqueInWebService> ConstructDestinationMapPropsList(List<BoutiqueInWebService> datas)
{
    var result = new List<BoutiqueInWebService>(datas);
    return result;
}
```

or change your parameter to be of type `List<DestinationGenericMapProps>`:

```
private List<DestinationGenericMapProps> ConstructDestinationMapPropsList(List<DestinationGenericMapProps> datas)
{
    var result = new List<DestinationGenericMapProps>(datas);
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, if you know how to make a `DestinationGenericMapProps` from a `BoutiqueInWebService`, you can use `System.Linq` and perform a select against the argument:

```
private List<DestinationGenericMapProps> ConstructDestinationMapPropsList(List<BoutiqueInWebService> datas)
{
    var result = datas.Select(x => new DestinationGenericMapProps() { ... }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you're trying to populate a list of one type (DestinationGenericMapProps) with objects from a list of a different type (BoutiqueInWebService) which isn't type safe.

You can only do this if BoutiqueInWebService inherits from DestinationGenericMapProps.

Answer (score 1):

C# supports function overloading, which means that a class can have more than one function with the same name as long as the parameters are different. The compiler decides which overload to call by compairing the types of the parameters. This applies to constructors too.

The List class has a three overloads of its constuctor:

```
List<T>()
List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)
List<T>(int)
```

I assume that you are trying to use the second of those as it will create a new list from the passed in one. For the list you are creating T is a DestinationGenericMapProps. So the constructors are:

```
List<DestinationGenericMapProps>()
List<DestinationGenericMapProps>(IEnumerable<DestinationGenericMapProps>)
List<DestinationGenericMapProps>(int)
```

The list you have passed in has T set to BoutiqueInWebService. As such the compiler is trying to find a constructor like this in the list above.

```
List<DestinationGenericMapProps>(IEnumerable<BoutiqueInWebService>)
```

As it can't find one it raises the error you have recieved.

Is it possible to cast a BoutiqueInWebService to a DestinationGenericMapProps object? If so you could do this:

```
var result = datas.Cast<DestinationGenericMapProps>().ToList()
```

If no direct cast is possible it may be possible to do a long hand cast like this:

```
var result = datas.Select(o => new DestinationGenericMapProps() { PropA = o.PropA, PropB = o.PropB /* etc */}).ToList();
```